# Should there be a direct resource route for any nested route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-api

I have a class User and a class Task. My resource route for tasks are nested inside the User resource and tasks belong_to users and users have_many tasks.

```
resources :users, except: [:new, :edit] do
  resources :tasks, except: [:new, :edit] 
end
```

In my rspec "requests"  test I am trying to POST a new task with an associated user but it looks like it's trying to hit a direct `/tasks` route eventually which it does not find. The test passes if my routes file looks like this for example:

```
  resources :users, except: [:new, :edit] do
    resources :tasks, except: [:new, :edit] 
  end

  resources :tasks, except: [:new, :edit]
```

The test looks like this (there is a `before(:each)` that creates a `@user1`):

```
  describe "POST /users/1/tasks" do
    it "creates a new task for user1" do
        post user_tasks_path(@user1, task: {description: "post new task", due_date: "2/1/15", user_id: @user1.id})
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
        puts response.body
    end
  end
```

Comment: what is `rake routes` printing out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not compulsory to have direct resource for nested ones.

Now, regarding your spec. I'm not sure it's trying to reach `/tasks`, but please mind the syntax for the [`post`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L514) method:

```
post(action, *args)
```

That said, you should be doing:

```
post(user_tasks_path(@user1), task: {})
```

instead of:

```
post(user_tasks_path(@user1, task: {}))
```

HTH.

Comment: Actually this only works if my routes file has the nested and explicit path. If I just have the nested one, I get no method task_url for TasksController. Any ideas?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be. If you only have the nested `[user, task]` route, you will only get the `user_task*` helpers. You can check your routes and helpers with the `rake routes` command.

Comment: I realized why I was getting that error. In the create action in the tasks controller, it had: 

 if (at)task.save
      render json: (at)task, status: :created, location: (at)task

which I think was routing to "task_url." If I changed location: (at)task to an interpolated string like "location: users/#{(at)user.id}/tasks/#{(at)task.id}", it works! (NOTE: replace (at) with the at symbol)